# Django Admin get_fieldsets not working with classes extrapretty and wide

Tags: python, django-forms, django-admin

I am using Django 1.5 and I want to use **extrapretty** and **wide** in the admin.

I tried adding the following to the **get_fieldsets** method:

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        return [ (None, {'classes': ('wide', 'extrapretty')}),
                 (None, {'fields': ('testfield')}) ]

    return [ (None, {'classes': ('wide', 'extrapretty')}),
             (None, {'fields': ('testfield1', 'testfield2')}) ]
```

This does not work - the admin appears the same - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* your problem is that `classes` and `fields` are supposed to be keys in the same dict.  I think that your code is creating 2 fieldsets: the first having no classes and the second one having no fields

Have you tried:

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
        return [ (None, {'classes': ('wide', 'extrapretty'),
                         'fields': ('testfield')}) ]

    return [ (None, {'classes': ('wide', 'extrapretty'),
                     'fields': ('testfield1', 'testfield2')}) ]
```